# How does one initialize a rectangle class with two points, topLeft point (0,0) and bottomRight point (1,1) in python?

Tags: python

I want to be able to create a rectangle where it has the data attribute of two points defining two opposite corners of a rectangle as, use the Points defined above, not using inheritance. But I am having trouble with the initialization method in the rectangle class and a few methods and not sure if I am going about this the correct way. I want the **init**: initialize with default p1 = (0,0), p2 = (1,1)

Here is what I have so far for the Point class:

```
import math

class Point:

    def __init__(self, x: float = 0.0, y: float = 0.0)->None:
        self.x = x # initialize to 0
        self.y = y # initialize to 0


    def moveIt(self, dx: float, dy: float)-> None:
        self.x = self.x + dx
        self.y = self.y + dy 

    def distance(self, otherPoint: float):
        if isinstance(otherPoint, Point):
            x1 = self.x
            y1 = self.y
            x2 = otherPoint.x
            y2 = otherPoint.y

            return ( (x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 )**0.5
```

This all appears to work as expecte when I create a point.

```
p1 = Point()

print(p1.x, p1.y)

>>>> 0 0
```

But my Rectangle class is not working when I create a blank Rectangle object. Here is the code:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft, bottomRight):
        self.topLeft = 0,0
        self.bottomRight = 1,1
```

I can't seem to find a way to have like I had it in the Point class where the Point is initialized from the get go to x=0, and y=0. Is there any way to do this in the Rectangle class? I tried the following but it wasn't allowed:

```
Class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft = (0,0), bottomRight = (1,1)):
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight
```

When I run the code I get errors that I cannot initialize like this.

```
r1 = Rectangle()

print(r1.topLeft, r1.bottomRight)
```

After the initialization I want to be able to pass in Points I made.

Finally, from this I am trying to create two methods Get_area to return the area of the rectangle as a floating point value and Get_perimeter to return the perimeter as a floating point value.

Comment: You probably just need to `new Point(0,0)` rather than just `(0,0)`.

Comment: Thank you. How would that be written for the init method? I tried   def __init__(self, new Point(0,0) topLeft, new Point(1,1) bottomRight):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote `Class` instead of `class`. Your code works fine when it is rectified

You **wrote**

```
Class Rectangle:
```

You **should** write

```
class Rectangle:
```

Complete:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft = (0,0), bottomRight = (1,1)):
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight

r1 = Rectangle()
print(r1.topLeft, r1.bottomRight)    
> (0, 0) (1, 1)
```

Use the following way to override the default values

```
r1 = Rectangle(topLeft = (0,0.5), bottomRight = (1,1))
```

Edit 2: Overriding the defaults

```
p1 = (3,5) 
p2 = (6,10)
r1 = Rectangle() 
print (r1.topLeft, r1.bottomRight)
> (0, 0) (1, 1)

r2 = Rectangle(p1, p2)
print (r2.topLeft, r2.bottomRight)
> (3, 5) (6, 10)
```

Comment: That was a typo, my bad.

Comment: When I run it as: r1 = Rectangle() I get the error: TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'topLeft' and 'bottomRight'

Comment: Strange, I just copy pasted it in a fresh notebook and it works for me. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Yes that is it! Thank you so much!

Comment: How could I have it to where it would replace the default values of 0,0 and 1,1? I'd love to be able to pass in new point locations. When I tried it, it sent back the memory location instead of the point location.

Comment: Thanks. There is no way to override the defaults from where it stands now to say creating p1 = Point(3,5) and p2 = (6,10) and then doing r1 = Rectangle() and r2 = Rectangle(p1, p2)?

Comment: Josh actually wants `topLeft` & `bottomRight` to be `Points` instances.

Comment: Is there another way to initialize the topLeft and bottomRight points that would allow for the later replacement of those default values?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you want. Doing r1 = Rectangle() will show the default values and then r2 = Rectangle(p1, p2) will override the default values and show `r2.topLeft, r2.bottomRight` as `(3, 5), (6, 10)`

Comment: I'd like to be able to have the default initialization of Rectangle as two points topLeft (0,0) and bottomRight (1,1) but then later be able to replace them if I were to create another object and put in the parameter Rectangle two point instances.

Comment: When I wrote this: p1 = (3,5) and p1 = (6,10) and r1 = Rectangle(p1.topLeft,p2.bottomRight) I go <__main__.Point object at 0x000002049DDA02B0> <__main__.Point object at 0x000002049DDA02E8>

Comment: But that's exactly what r1 = Rectangle() and  r2 = Rectangle(p1, p2) will do, right? First r1 = Rectangle() will initialize default and then r2 = Rectangle(p1, p2) will override the default

Comment: For some reason it doesn't print the values just the memory location or that string of zeros of and letters.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want them as tuples, but Point objects. I probably shouldn't have used tuples in the parameters. Yeah this is a weird one.

Comment: I was thinking on the lines of: def __init__(self, topLeft = Point(0,0), bottomRight = Point(1,1)): but that still returns a memory location.

Comment: This gives what you want: `p1 = Point(3,5)` `p2 = Point(6,10)` `r2 = Rectangle(p1, p2)` `print (r2.topLeft.x, r2.topLeft.y)`